# Python - Calling Dictionary w/ 2 Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, pulp

I have a dictionary with 2 keys (i and j) that are the same as indices in a data frame. 
Example of data frame - demands for different i and j pairings.

---

```
i   j   Demand
0   1   13
0   2   24
0   3   68
0   4   92
0   5   72
0   6   11
0   7   12
0   8   6
0   9   4
0   10  3
1   1   0
1   2   11
1   3   15
.   .   .
```

The i's go from 0 to 9 and the j's repeat for each i from 1 to 10.
A dictionary for bookings accepted was built off of this demand as such:

```
bookingsaccepted = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("bookingsaccepted",
                  ((i, j) for i, j in demand.index), lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
```

And now I am trying to reference values in the bookings accepted dictionary. I am trying to set a constraint in pulp so that all the (i,j) pairs where i=0 are summed together. I am using this but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
model += pulp.lpSum( [bookingsaccepted[(0,j)] for j in demand.index] ) <= capacity
```

Gives error:
KeyError: (0, (0, 1))

Comment: From your above post it looks like `demand.index` returns tuples so you need to get just a unique set of the second item. `model += pulp.lpSum( [bookingsaccepted[(0,j)] for j in set(b) for a,b in demand.index] ) <= capacity`

Answer (score 2):

That looks like your `demand.index` consists of pairs `(i, j)`. Look here you iterate through `demand.index` and it brings i and j:

```
bookingsaccepted = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("bookingsaccepted",
              ((i, j) for i, j in demand.index), lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
```

So, when you're iterating `demand.index` you get a tuples `(i, j)`. If you need to get only `j`, do so:

```
model += pulp.lpSum( [bookingsaccepted[(0,j)] for i, j in demand.index] ) <= capacity
```

or

```
model += pulp.lpSum( [bookingsaccepted[(0,index[1])] for index in demand.index] ) <= capacity
```

Comment: Why then does this code not provide same results: 'model += bookingsaccepted[(0,1)]  + bookingsaccepted[(0,2)] + bookingsaccepted[(0,3)] + bookingsaccepted[(0,4)] + bookingsaccepted[(0,5)] + bookingsaccepted[(0,6)]  \
         + bookingsaccepted[(0,7)] + bookingsaccepted[(0,8)]+ bookingsaccepted[(0,9)] + bookingsaccepted[(0,10)] <= capacity'

Comment: There are completely different meaning between `lpSum(...) <= num` and `sum(...) <= num`.

Comment: Also gives different results than: 'for i,j in demand.index:
    if i==0:
        model += pulp.lpSum( bookingsaccepted[i,j] ) <= capacity
    else:
        break'

Comment: `pulp.lpSum(..) <= capacity` creates a new constraint. You add all your elements and set it to be less or equal the capacity, but that's not the same, when you create a constraint for each element. You create completely different sets of constraints and add in to your model. That's absolutely different things.

Comment: Thank you. The code that worked was: `model += pulp.lpSum( [bookingsaccepted[(i,j)] for i, j in demand.index if i==0] ) <= capacity`